# How to open a child windows under parent window on menu item click in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, modal-dialog

I am developing an application in C#. I'm using .Net under WPF. I want to open a new child window (like a dialog) and it should open within the main window, just below the menu bar.

However, the newly opened windows is simply showing an OS task bar. How can I open the various new windows(like a dialog box) under the main window?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this.

```
MyChildWindow cw = new MyChildWindow();
cw.ShowInTaskbar = false;
cw.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
cw.Show();
```

Comment: If you have multiple windows and the Application.Current.MainWindow is not the desired Window, You could use VisualTreeHelper.GetParent to traverse the tree until you reach the current window.

Comment: For a dialog, you should use ShowDialog as opposed to Show.